# Facebooker + Devise = "like_it" button : "b is undefined"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, facebook, integration, facebooker

I'm using devise with the facebooker plugin.

What is the best option to make a "like_it" button on my webpage without the iframe approach ?

I have

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"></script>`

What should I do to get the `<fb:like href="http://myurl.com</fb:like>` working ?

When I insert the Facebook SDK javascript library, I get an "b is undefined error"

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I tried to load both the OLD javascript SDK (FeatureLoader.js.php), and the NEW Javascript SDK on the same page. Those libraries are not compatible.